# pointer to rvalue

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, rvalue

While searching a solution for calling a function that accepts both lvalue and rvalue references I wrote the following piece of code (no, I will never do that again, I promise).

The goal was providing a function that both accepts lvalue and rvalue references, I did not want to write two functions or to really care about lvalue/rvalue on the caller's side. Therefore, I thought of providing some macro/function that wraps a parameter so it can be passed whether it's an l/rvalue - in this case get_addr.

In no case I would want to change data passed to the function.

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> get_addr(T t) {
    std::shared_ptr<T> p(new T(t));
    return p;
}

int get_value(int x){
    return x * 2;
}

void print_value(int* p){
    cout << *p << endl;
}

int main() {
    print_value(get_addr(get_value(42)).get());
}
```

While that code is working fine for me, I doubt it is safe. My guess: after calling get() from shared_ptr, the result of get_value() is not necessary anymore and could get dismissed. So, print_value could receive an invalid reference. Does that make sense? In any case, I do not like my code provided. I solved the issue by using a temporary variable.

Nevertheless, I'm still curious if there was any better solution for that problem. From the syntax' point of view, I'd like best only one function "void print_value(int&& p)" that accepts both l/rvalues. I've looked at move semantics, l/rvalue conversions but didn't find a solution that really looks nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In no case I would want to change data passed to the function.

What's wrong with this then?

```
void print_value(int p){
    cout << p << endl;
}
```

Or the following, if you don't want to copy some expensive type.

```
void print_value(T const& p){
    cout << p << endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's my solution. Though so simple, I did not see it. I've not been aware of the fact that rvalue references can be passed as long as the reference parameter is marked const. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can just take `const T&`, and it will bind to both l and r values. However, more directly, "Perfect Forwarding" is the solution to this problem.